# Relocated /var - now selinux is unhappy

Tags: centos, selinux

I needed more space in the /var tree on a VM so I allocated some, booted in to runlevel 1 and copied over the folder to the new space. After changing the fstab entry for /var to reflect the new location I rebooted.

(you can see what's coming)

The boot process was pretty well mangled. I had to disable selinux to get anything working properly.

Given the nature of this system I would like to reenable selinux but I'm not clear how to get it all setup properly. Looking at the perms using `ls -Z` it all appears the same (as the original /var folder) but clearly something is amiss.

What step(s) did I miss?

EDIT:  This is the (relevant) output of `ls -alZ /`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root  root     ?                                var
drwxr-xr-x. root  root     system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       var.old
```

Looks like a promising avenue - though I note that /sys, /dev and /proc all have '?' there.

Comment: What are the permissions on the /var directory?  This could be throwing selinux for a loop.  When you mount a volume on a directory, it doesn't inherit the permissions of the directory, it has its own permissions.

Answer (score 6):

Should be a pretty simple fix:

1. Set SELinux to *permissive*. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and set `SELINUX=permissive`. This should let you boot normally while still being able to use SELinux utilities.
2. Reboot the system.
3. Restore all the file contexts for the entire system.

   ```
   restorecon -r -v /
   ```
4. Set SELinux to enforcing. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and set `SELINUX=enforcing`.
5. Reboot the system.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to apply the security settings to the /var mount point.  Do you have any other mount points, say for /usr?